# Is there an age difference limit for marriages in halakha?

Tags: halacha, marriage, age

What is the biggest age gap permitted by halakha between a man and a girl/woman for them to get married?

Comment: Is there a basis to your assumption that such a gap exists?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yevamot.12.6.2?lang=bi
Also mentioned in Bavli Yevamos 44A and 101B. Exact ages aren’t mentioned, but old with young is discouraged, and according to many, by yibum it is actually not allowed

Comment: @Chatzkel but what do they mean by old man? Is for example the gap of 9 years normal in halakha and is permitted?

Comment: Definitely permitted. As to what age gap is too big, individuals are probably much better off consulting a rabbi regarding their specific situation.

Comment: @N.T. The thing is there is no rabbi in the country where I live. I am a non-jew by the way.

Comment: Ok, but asking advice from us is probably not going to be so helpful. You might as well flip a coin. Sorry. I hope your situation works out for the best.

Comment: Jewish marriage is not some kind of a romantic enterprise - it is a means to fulfill heavenly commandments. So unless the man is sterile, there can be no limitations. Look at the forefathers, Isaac (37) married Rivka (3), Jacob (84) married Rachel and Lea (20), and more.

Answer (score 5):

There is no age gap explicitly mentioned in halacha. However, there is a general depreciation in The Talmud for marrying two people of significantly different ages.

"Who marries his daughter to an old man, or who takes an old woman as a wife for a young son, to him the verse refers, "To add drunkenness to thirst; the Lord will not pardon him" (Deuteronomy 29. 19f) (Sanhedrin 76b).

"If he was young and she old, or vice versa, they [the elders] would say to him "What sense is there in your marrying one much younger than yourself? or "What sense is there in your marrying one much older than yourself? Go, marry one who is about your own age and do not introduce strife into your house" (Jebamoth 101b).

Comment: Welcome to MY, and thank you for this well-sourced answer!